# Преобразование графической математической функции в её формулу

Tags: математика

У меня есть определённая функция, только в графическом отображении. Например, синусойда. Мне нужно из изображения функции получить её формулу (то бишь y=sin(x))
Существует ли возможность реализовать данный алгоритм?

Comment: В общем случае - готового алгоритма нет.  Но есть подходы работающие в частных случаях, подбора коэффициентов методами оптимизации, преобразование Фурье , ...  и до нейросетей.

Comment: А можно более подробно про возможные подходы?

Comment: Вот здесь есть видео, кажется, как это делается: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nci9v-QJwxc